# @NotNull Annotation does not work on Double

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, dropwizard

I am trying to validate Double in the request of my dropwizard application. Below is the code for same

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@PATH("/path")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    public Response addNumber( @QueryParam("first") @NotNull Double first, @QueryParam("second") @NotNull Double second) {
       return Response.ok("added").build();
    }
}
```

I get the below error when querying the resource localhost/path?first=46.76&second=67.56

```
{
    "errors": [
        "query param first may not be null",
        "query param second may not be null"
    ]
}
```

If we remove the `@NotNull` from the resource the resource responds successfully.

Why does `@NotNull` say it should be not null although the values are present?

Comment: double will always evaluate to `0` incase it doesn't exist

Comment: What version of Dropwizard are you using? If you are indeed specifying a valid double like you mentioned in your question `localhost/path?first=46.76&second=67.56`  you shouldn't see this error. I just tested in Dropwizard `1.3.5` and I don't see this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. So implemented custom validator.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotZeroDoubleValidatorImpl.class)
public @interface NotZeroDoubleValidator {
    String message() default "{Double value is required}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * Field to validate against 0.
     */
    double field() default 0;
}
```

And

```
public class NotZeroDoubleValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<NotZeroDoubleValidator, Double> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final NotZeroDoubleValidator notZeroDoubleValidator) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Double value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return Double.compare(value, 0) != 0;
    }

}
```